# Java Windows 8 Full Screen?

Tags: java, fullscreen, windows-8

I have this code inside my class `MainWindow`:

```
public MainWindow() {
    super("Shouldn't be visible...");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));

    addFocusListener(new FocusLostExiter());
    addKeyListener(new EscListener());

    setContentPane(canvas);

    getContentPane().setPreferredSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    pack();
    setResizable(false);
}

public void setFullScreen(boolean b) {
    if(!b) {
        device.setFullScreenWindow(null);
    }
    setVisible(b);
    //System.out.println(device.getFullScreenWindow());
    if(b) {
        device.setFullScreenWindow(this);
    }
}
```

In Windows 7+Java 6, it works as full screen just fine.  I can click anywhere without problems.  However, in Windows 8+Java 6, all of the leftmost column of pixels except for about 100 near the top, and a box where the start button should be, are messed up.  In the column and the box, my cursor changes to a normal mouse again and the window ignores my clicks.  In the start box, clicking brings up the start menu instead of giving my program a click event.  This seems to be a problem with Java, cause it works everywhere but W8.  Do you know what's wrong/how to fix or get around it?

Comment: Windows 8 is still beta, so don't expect perfect compatibility with your drivers and Java VM.

Comment: But can we expect it to be fixed?

Comment: When Windows 8 has launched, they will be working on a fix, maybe before ;) It has to be fixed, but I don't know when.

Comment: Windows 8 is different than Windows 7.
It aims at compatibility with mobile devices. Then, it works the other way that is not compatible with the JVM yet.

Comment: If _it works everywhere but W8_ I'd say it's a problem with Win8, not Java.

Comment: dumb one, have you tried windows 8+java 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never answered this properly... It was an issue with the JRE on Windows 8 itself. Now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem before, the bottom of the window was getting cut off on Windows machines, and adding in these lines fixed the issue:

```
frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Assuming that your MainWindow class extends JFrame, calling these two methods should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
public NewFrame(){

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    this.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());

    this.setVisible(true);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your MainWindow class is a JFrame, then you don't have to use `getContentPane()`. I don't think you need the setFullScreen function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out for full screen, usually it is preferred to use half the width and height of the original screen size

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolKit();

Dimension d = toolkit.getScreenSize();

int w = d.width;

int h = d.height;

setSize(w,h);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily just place this inside your constructor

```
 Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
 setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
```